# Cannot access a disposed object but the program works

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

IN WPF project, whenever I try to add selected Student in selected university and display it on assoiated table.
Here is image of my table -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUHuF.png
I encounter this problem, once I hit update assosiated button.

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Student> Students
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Student>();
        }
    }
```

The above code is in "Dataclasses1.designer.cs" window.
However, upon restarting the program, selected student is sucessfully added to selected university.
Here is my code -

```
 private void UpdateAssociatedStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ListUniversity.SelectedItem != null || ListStudent.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            using (dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                UniversityManager universityManager = new UniversityManager
                {
                    UniFK = int.Parse(ListUniversity.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                    StdFK = int.Parse(ListStudent.SelectedValue.ToString())
                };
                dataContext.UniversityManagers.InsertOnSubmit(universityManager);
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
            ShowAssociatedStudents();
            Sucess.Text = "Student is sucessfully added to University";
        }
    }
```

Edit - Adding image for error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApPxd.png

Comment: Please include exactly what the exception is, and on what line of code it occurs.

Comment: Hy Keith,
I've added an image to show where the problem occurs. It's in "DataClasses1.designer.cs"
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Student> Students
  {
   get
   {
    return this.GetTable<Student>();
   }
  }

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use this code :`if(ListUniversity.SelectedItem != null || ListStudent.SelectedItem != null)` the logic will pass if one of the parameters under test is NULL

Comment: What is the content of `ShowAssociatedStudents()` ?

Comment: Hy Gaz,
Are you referring to code?
public void ShowAssociatedStudents(){if (ListUniversity.SelectedItem != null) {var showAssociatedStudents = from Std in dataContext.Students join uM in dataContext.UniversityManagerson Std.StudentId equals uM.StdFKjoin Uni in dataContext.Universities on uM.UniFK equals Uni.UniversityIdwhere uM.UniFK == int.Parse(ListUniversity.SelectedValue.ToString())select uM.Student; ListShowAssociatedStudents.ItemsSource = showAssociatedStudents; ListShowAssociatedStudents.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";ListShowAssociatedStudents.SelectedValuePath = "StudentId";}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may need to change this line of code:

`if(ListUniversity.SelectedItem != null || ListStudent.SelectedItem != null)`

to

`if(ListUniversity.SelectedItem != null && ListStudent.SelectedItem != null)`

Comment: Hy Chris, Thank you for pointing that out. I've made the changes although it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by running try/catch instead of using 'Using' statement. my edited code looks like this.

```
 //Add selected student from selected university in associated student listbox
    private void UpdateAssociatedStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ListUniversity.SelectedItem != null && ListStudent.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            try
            {
                uniManager = new UniversityManager()
                {
                    UniFK = Convert.ToInt32(ListUniversity.SelectedValue),
                    StdFK = Convert.ToInt32(ListStudent.SelectedValue)
                    //UniFK = int.Parse(ListUniversity.SelectedItem.ToString()),
                    //StdFK = int.Parse(ListStudent.SelectedItem.ToString())
                };
                dataContext.UniversityManagers.InsertOnSubmit(uniManager);
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                ShowAssociatedStudents();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Not Found.");
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Out of Memory.");
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An I/O error has occured.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Failed.Text = "Please select the missing items from either university or student.";
        }
    }
```